# Wordpress wp_nav_menu()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to build a WordPress menu and having trouble remove the default id's given to the li's. I have successfully used $menu_id and $menu_class to rename the ul id's and classes, but can't seem to figure it out in case of li's.

I need my menu to look like

```
<ul id="menubar">   
<li><a href="/" class="main home active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About_us" class="main about-us">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="Mission" class="main mission">Mission</a></li>
</ul>
```

instead of

```
<ul id="menubar" class="">
     <li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-7"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `nav_menu_item_id` filter. In `wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php`, it is used as followed:

```
    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';
```

This means that you just have to add a function to return a 'falsy' value to prevent an ID attribute from being generated. To do so, simply add the following to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function mytheme_remove_nav_menu_item_id( $id ) {
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'mytheme_remove_nav_menu_item_id' );
```